# Why does the length of my list have to include -1 to accomodate a +1 in my for loop?

Tags: python

I'm doing an online python course and don't understand how the range of my list is functioning with a sorting program.

This code works but I don't understand why the negative 1 is necessary in

```py
for i in range(len(myList)-1):
```

I tried breaking the code by removing it which worked.  apparently without the '-1' line 6 is out of range.  So I understand it is necessary in order for the code to run but I don't understand why taking the length and apparently subtracting 1 from it expands the range.

```py
myList = [8, 10, 6, 2, 4] # list to sort
swapped = True # it's a little fake - we need it to enter the while loop

while swapped:
    swapped = False # no swaps so far
    for i in range(len(myList) - 1):
        if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:
            swapped = True # swap occured!
            myList[i], myList[i + 1] = myList[i + 1], myList[i]

print(myList)
```

Comment: *taking the length and apparently subtracting 1 from it expands the range* that's not what's going on here. You're comparing an item at index `i` to the *next* item (`i+1`). Clearly, when you're at the last item in your list, item `i+1` does not exist. So, an index error will raise. So you do the `-1` in order to iterate only until the *second-to-last* item in the list. This way, `i+1` is the index of the *last* item in the list.

Comment: From a quick glance it is because you are doing a comparison using ```i + 1``` so if you went all the way to the last element you would get an error when trying to compare to i+1.

Comment: \ Can you checkmark my answer if it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Len(mylist) is equal to 5. However, myList[5] will throw and error because it is out of bounds. Because you are adding one to "i" in the second to last line there will be an error. Most programming languages start counting from 0 up to 1 less than the length of the list.

Comment: @GeeTransit What question did I make. How did I answer my own question?

Comment: That makes total sense. I forgot that len would give me an output starting at 1 and python is working from 0.  So in essence, I'm not changing the length, just aligning it.  Cool! that makes sense!

Comment: Len just gives the length of an list. There is no `output starting at` there. Just to be clear

Comment: @BlueRineS Nice clarification

Comment: so rephrasing: len starts counting at 1 and gives the length of the list as 5, whereas within the for loop, python begins counting at 0 and understands the last element as element 4 and doesn't care about the length of the list itself.  Therefor, ```python  for i in range(len(myList) - 1) ``` now brings those 2 processes into alignment and compares 0,1,2,3,4 with 0,1,2,3,4, am I thinking about this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `range` you are effectively creating an iterable like a list, or set that starts ats and goes up not including. Meaning that,

```
range(1, 53)
```

would essentially create a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...] that goes from 1 all the way up to fifty-three not including it. For a total of 52 elements. However, when creating a range where you are certain that you will be accessing an element ahead of time such as using i+1, you must account for that with a -1 in the actual range to allow for proper indexing and no errors.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).